# Retrieving raw request from Nest's Get API Call (Nest version: 6.4.2)

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest

I am just trying to do what I wrote in the title.

My code is as follow:

`var response= elasticClient.Get<MyPoco>(guid,i => i.Index(this.configurationProxy.ConfigurationObject.ElasticIndex));`

`var rawQuery = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(searchResponse.ApiCall.ResponseBodyInBytes);`

I am just trying to get the Kibana query that it does in the Get API call to the elasticClient, is there something I am missing?

I need to have a rawQuery in response since I need to be sure to be able to replicate my calls in Kibana after I have setted everything up.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to get search request which was actually sent to Elasticsearch you can enable debug mode when creating `ElasticClient` with `new ElasticClient(new ConnectionSettings().EnableDebugMode())`.

With this, `response.DebugInformation` will contain request sent to Elasticsearch.

You can read more about debug mode in [docs](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/current/debug-mode.html).